# What causes a reputation change when "There were no net reputation changes on this day?"

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, reputation-history

Looking at a certain user's rep history, I noticed some days had +10 and -10 with no explanation of the reputation change on the detail dropdown.

[image: Reputation]

What can cause this?  Is this the result of moderator intervention?  Is this a bug?

I've raised a custom moderator flag on this question in an effort to provide more information to the mods without singling-out this user and situation publicly.

I'm not sure this case is identical to the linked duplicate.  That question specifically asks about a net change of 0 rep, not a positive or negative score for that day (unless the scenario is the same).  I think this might be a bug.

Comment: Probably the only posts that existed were removed for that day - however, the score/votes still remain because it was done outside the 60 days for them to be automatically retracted.

Comment: Although having said that - it happened to you on April 16th - but not the reason I guessed at... so... I'm confused :)

Comment: @JonClements April 16th of this year?  I see a rep change of +1 on that day due to the deletion of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193678/minify-index-php/36653794#36653794) (that I downvoted)

Comment: Just a guesswork. A user who upvoted had been removed. Does it make sense?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev nah, it does show a message when that happens: http://i.imgur.com/Uz2NZzO.png

Comment: @rmobis no other ideas. I hope moderators know better.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as I've already discussed in my question.  If the reputation changing events canceled each outer out, this would show a net score of 0 for the day rather than + or - 10.

Comment: Perhaps the user downvoted some answers? Does downvoting answers show in the reputation history if it is not your profile?

Comment: @cybermonkey Although possible, I find it unlikely since it doesn't fall into the previous rep patterns associated with this user.  But definitely a possibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big thank you to [Undo♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) for investigating this for me today!

The +10 and -10 were from upvotes and unupvotes on a now deleted post.  This is only visible to mods.

[image: Mod Info]

Comment: If this is on your own rep history, it should show up if you click the 'show removed posts' checkbox. But if it's not, you can't see it.

Comment: @hichris123 as stated in the question, this is another user's rep history.

Comment: Oh, [Jon's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323001/what-causes-a-reputation-change-when-there-were-no-net-reputation-changes-on-th/323150?noredirect=1#comment344036_323001) made me think it was your own, sorry.

Comment: @hichris123 no worries, great to point it out.